# Is it possible to consume the ActiveAdmin API endpoints alone with a custom UI and a frontend framework like Angular/React?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Just been researching about this approach and never seem to find a concrete answer online.

I'm seriously curious about the chances of only consuming the API for activeadmin. Then using the JSON objects in React or Angular with a custom UI.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory it is possible since you would just be using the endpoints provided but I think it would be far a far better design choice to choose another API framework gem like [grape](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape). One of my complaints with ActiveAdmin has always been that it is not very flexible and you can quickly run into limitations which means that you can't add features that you want to. IMHO you would be digging a pit instead of opening possibilities.

Personally I really like GraphQL (which would be another option) and the [graphql-ruby](https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby) gem is easy to set up and start making highly reusable components that can be leveraged from anywhere admin or frontend.

Comment: Thanks, Tyrone for your comment and answer. You are right, that's exactly why there's no one discussing this online. 
Are you proposing that we build our own admin API from scratch and then consume the API in whatever framework we want?

Comment: That would be my approach but I don't know your specific requirements. There is a better option for "out of the box" admin which would be RailsAdmin. Much more flexible but still gives you loads for free https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin

Comment: There's actually no specific requirements, we just want to be able to create a custom admin interface, with beautiful UI where we can "CRUD" our model data, do some data analytics by integrating charts and much more.. And we want full control of the JSON object. Thanks I'll take a look at rails_admin.

Comment: For full control over the JSON object I would HIGHLY HIGHLY recommend you check out graphql. This allows for 'client driven' api where your frontend can dictate what data and in what shape. It is also self documenting using something like GraphiQL. Hit me up on linkedin if you need any further help :)

Comment: Okay, I've added you on LinkedIn. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely! See https://blog.heroku.com/a-rock-solid-modern-web-stack

For notes on ActiveAdmin vs Rails Admin and other alternatives see https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Alternatives

I've also used both Grape and GraphQL in different places, one for performance, the other for flexibility, both reasonable choices.